# Getting error java.io.FileNotFoundException (log4j log file) at the time of publish project on cloudfoundry

Tags: java, log4j, cloud-foundry

I am planing to move web application to cloudfoundry along with mysql service. But I am getting below error.

Its working fine with local environment. log file get generated also.

**Below is error log:**

```
Jan 5, 2013 7:35:59 AM org.cloudfoundry.reconfiguration.AbstractServiceConfigurer configure
INFO: No beans of type org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.ConnectionFactory found in application context
Jan 5, 2013 7:35:59 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
SEVERE: Error listenerStart
Jan 5, 2013 7:35:59 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
SEVERE: Context [] startup failed due to previous errors
log4j:WARN Continuable parsing error 109 and column 23
log4j:WARN The content of element type "log4j:configuration" must match "(renderer*,appender*,plugin*,(category|logger)*,root?,(categoryFactory|loggerFactory)?)".
log4j:ERROR setFile(null,true) call failed.
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /logs/abc-web.log (No such file or directory)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.openAppend(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:177)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:102)
    at org.apache.log4j.FileAppender.setFile(FileAppender.java:290)
    at org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender.setFile(RollingFileAppender.java:194)
    at org.apache.log4j.FileAppender.activateOptions(FileAppender.java:164)
    at org.apache.log4j.config.PropertySetter.activate(PropertySetter.java:257)
    at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.parseAppender(DOMConfigurator.java:285)
    at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.findAppenderByName(DOMConfigurator.java:171)
    at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.findAppenderByReference(DOMConfigurator.java:184)
    at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.parseChildrenOfLoggerElement(DOMConfigurator.java:502)
    at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.parseRoot(DOMConfigurator.java:471)
    at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.parse(DOMConfigurator.java:921)
    at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.doConfigure(DOMConfigurator.java:790)
    at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.doConfigure(DOMConfigurator.java:696)
    at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.configure(DOMConfigurator.java:821)
    at org.springframework.util.Log4jConfigurer.initLogging(Log4jConfigurer.java:69)
    at org.springframework.web.util.Log4jWebConfigurer.initLogging(Log4jWebConfigurer.java:151)
    at org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener.contextInitialized(Log4jConfigListener.java:45)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4705)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:799)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:779)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:601)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1079)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectories(HostConfig.java:1002)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:506)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1317)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:324)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1065)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:840)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1057)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:463)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:525)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:754)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:595)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
log4j:ERROR LogMananger.repositorySelector was null likely due to error in class reloading, using NOPLoggerRepository.
Stopping Tomcat because the context stopped.
```

log4j.xml:

```
<appender name="fileAppender" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
    <param name="MaxFileSize" value="25MB" />
    <param name="MaxBackupIndex" value="10" />
    <param name="File" value="/logs/abc-web.log" />
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d [%t] %-5p: %m (%c)%n" />
    </layout>
</appender>
```

Comment: Show us your code, @Mohan

Answer (score 4):

I had this same issue of the FileNotFound exception.

My solution was to remove the appended "/" from the value as so:

```
<param name="File" value="logs/abc-web.log" />
```

Comment: But this changes the directory of log file.

Comment: Where to change this?

Answer (score 2):

Log4j will [create directories](https://github.com/apache/log4j/blob/trunk/src/main/java/org/apache/log4j/FileAppender.java) while the directory and it's parent directory not exists.

Log4j throws FileNotFoundException while creating directory or file failed without file priviledge.

Check the file priviledge with your app user.

```
  public
  synchronized
  void setFile(String fileName, boolean append, boolean bufferedIO, int bufferSize)
                                                            throws IOException {
    LogLog.debug("setFile called: "+fileName+", "+append);

    // It does not make sense to have immediate flush and bufferedIO.
    if(bufferedIO) {
      setImmediateFlush(false);
    }

    reset();
    FileOutputStream ostream = null;
    try {
          //
          //   attempt to create file
          //
          ostream = new FileOutputStream(fileName, append);
    } catch(FileNotFoundException ex) {
          //
          //   if parent directory does not exist then
          //      attempt to create it and try to create file
          //      see bug 9150
          //
          String parentName = new File(fileName).getParent();
          if (parentName != null) {
             File parentDir = new File(parentName);
             if(!parentDir.exists() && parentDir.mkdirs()) {
                ostream = new FileOutputStream(fileName, append);
             } else {
                throw ex;
             }
          } else {
             throw ex;
          }
    }
```

Comment: Where i should check? who gives privileges?

Comment: I am using cloudFoundry plugin in STS(eclipse), is there any option to give permission? please help me.

Comment: check this: http://support.cloudfoundry.com/entries/20024127-how-will-we-get-local-filesystem-access

Comment: Maybe you should not use file system. Using org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender in log4j or other appends.

Comment: You could also use RabbitMQ to post log messages somewhere rather than relying on local filesystem access.

Comment: it means i have to put extra work to handle log4j logging to external system like RabbitMQ. Does not sounds good.